# bibliography doesn't work well

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, biber

I have code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{biblatex} package}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{simpson}

Using \texttt{biblatex} you can display a bibliography divided
into sections, depending on citation type.  
\medskip
11111111111111
\printbibliography
22222222222222
\end{document}
```

And the file References.bib

```
@ARTICLE{Gill,
   author    = "A. E. Gill",
   title     = "Some Simple Solutions for Heat-Induced Tropical Circulation",
   journal   = "Quart. J. R. Met. Soc.",
   volume    = 106,
   year      = 1980,
   pages     = "447-462",
}
@ARTICLE{simpson,
   author    = "A. E. Gill77",
   title     = "Some Simple Solutions for Heat-Induced Tropical Circulation",
   journal   = "Quart. J. R. Met. Soc.",
   volume    = 106,
   year      = 1980,
   pages     = "447-462",
}
```

**BUT I'm getting this 1 page output**
[image]

So between the strings 11111111111 and 22222222222 the command
`\printbibliography` doesn't work.

**with this warning**

```
$ xelatex bib2.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bib2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/alphabetic.bbx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/alphabetic.cbx)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)) (./bib2.aux)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
(./bib2.bbl)

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 22.

[1] (./bib2.aux) )
Output written on bib2.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on bib2.log.
```

Comment: Did you run biber on your file?

Comment: You also don't seem to `\cite` anything? Without any `\cite`s, there is nothing `\printbibliography` could show.

Comment: You need to `\cite` something https://imgur.com/a/P83NQmo

Comment: @JamesT I have now `\cite{simpson}` but printbibliography still doesn't work. Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: How are you compiling this document? `pdflatex` -> `biber` -> `pdflatex`? Or are you on Overleaf

Comment: Your updated code works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpfPE.png Did you run `biber filename`?

Comment: It works fine for me too @user2925716, run `pdflatex`, then `biber`, then `pdflatex`

Comment: Can you post your command line inputs into your question please, will probably be more helpful. Edit into it exactly the inputs you are doing from the cmdline

Comment: @user2925716 ... and please also update the log file in your question to show the complete error message.

Comment: @JamesT It now works fine. But I have a problem: I'm writing everything in `WinEdt 10.3` and for getting `printbibliography` properly I must go to CMDLine (CygWin). Is there a way around it  ?

Comment: @user2925716 Compile with `latexmk filename`. This will automatically run all the necessary tools.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good. But I'm loosing `xetex`. How can I preserve this compilation tool ?

Comment: @user2925716 latexmk does have a `-xelatex` option

Comment: @user2925716 Are you sure that xelatex is a good choice? It neither has the speed advantage of pdflatex nor the power of lualatex. If you need an unicode aware engine, I would use lualatex. That's much less problematic nowadays. xelatex is such a pain with transparency etc.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz `latexmk filename` doesn't work. It apparently runs `biber` but gives no literature at the output at the end of the pdf document. On the other hand CMD line works fine to get bibliography. I have invested much effort into compilable `xetex` file and I cannot easily switch to other compiler. Also, I have some other documents in `xetex` :-(

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Also I have this `\index{Tarski}` and this `\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]` but the references in the Index are not clickable to return to they occurrence place. How can I fix it ?

Comment: As others have already establishes you need to run Biber. You can either do that manually, but if you use an editor that runs LaTeX and friends for you, it should also be possible to configure your editor to run Biber for you. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with that. (Of course you can still follow samcarter's advice and use the awesome `latexmk`. Surely, your editor can be convinced to run `latexmk` for you as well.)

Comment: The index issue is completely unrelated to the bibliography and there is no index in the example document shown here, so I suggest you ask a new question for that.